# Jstree: Loading json data asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous, jstree

I am currently trying to set up a Jstree, loading the data asynchronously from a webserver with the data provided in the json format. Before, I had the data stored in the html page itself, eg. by creating the `<ul> </ul>` structure. This worked well.

Then, following

http://agiliq.com/blog/2011/10/how-use-jstree/

I saved the data in the page as a Json string, which also worked fine. After that, I tried the asynchronous loading, where I encounter two problems:

1. When using Jstree jsTree 1.0-rc3 (as found in https://github.com/akshar-raaj/Using-jsTree), the tree structure is being built up correctly, but two expansion symbols appear left of each folder, which looks rather strange.
2. Then I tried to use the current version of Jstree, but this produces no tree at all and neither gives an error message.

Here is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">    
<html lang="en">    
<head>    
<title>Menu test</title>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/jsTree/themes/default/style.min.css" />    
<script src="/static/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    
<!--<script src="/static/jsTree/jstree.js"></script>-->    
<script src="/static/jsTree/jstree_v3.js"></script> <!-- Current Version -->    
<script>    
    $(function() {    
        $.ajax({    
        async : true,    
        type : "GET",    
        url : "../test2.json",    
        dataType : "json",        

        success : function(json) {    
            createJSTrees(json);    
        },        

        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {    
            alert(thrownError);    
        }    
        });    
    });        

    function createJSTrees(jsonData) {    
        $("#menuTree").jstree({    
        "json_data" : {    
            "data" : jsonData    
        },    
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]    
        });    
    }        
</script>    
</head>    
<body>    
Tree:    
<div id="menuTree" >    

</div>    

</body>    
</html>
```

And this is what test2.json gives out:

```
[ { "data" : "a", "children" :[ {"data":"b", "metadata":{"href":"b"}}, {"data":"c", "metadata":{"href":"c"}} ] } ]
```

Could you help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Per the first two examples here http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/, it doesn't appear that you are passing the data to the `.jstree()` method properly.

Comment: Thank you! I adapted my code to the examples given there, and it worked. I assume, in version 3 compared to version 1 they have changed how you give parameters to the jstree.